# data.frame with Date column ouput in RStudio console,preview, but not below the chunk

Tags: rstudio

Using Rstudio 3.3.2's notebook :

```
---
title: "R Notebook"
output: html_notebook
---
```

When trying to display a data.frame with a **Date column**, the data.frame is displayed in the Viewer tab, but not below the chunk itself :

````
    ```{r}
    df <- data.frame(date=c("31/08/2011", "31/07/2011", "30/06/2011"),values=c(0.8378,0.8457,0.8147))               

    #no Date format ->OK, output below the chunk
    df

    df$dateformatted<-as.Date(strptime(df$date,'%d/%m/%Y'))

    #with Date format -> NOK, no output below the chunk,only in Viewer.
    df 

    ```
````

RStudio diagnostics :

```
26 Feb 2017 20:42:00 [rsession-x] ERROR r error 7 (Unexpected data type); OCCURRED AT: rstudio::core::Error rstudio::r::json::{anonymous}::jsonValueFromVectorElement(SEXP, int, rstudio::core::json::Value*) /home/ubuntu/rstudio/src/cpp/r/RJson.cpp:149; LOGGED FROM: void rstudio::session::modules::rmarkdown::notebook::enqueueChunkOutput(const string&, const string&, const string&, unsigned int, ChunkOutputType, const rstudio::core::FilePath&, const Value&) /home/ubuntu/rstudio/src/cpp/session/modules/rmarkdown/NotebookOutput.cpp:449
```

relates to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41599004/how-can-i-print-tibbles-when-chunk-is-run-in-r-notebook-in-rstudio).

Does anyone knows what did I do wrong ? Thanks a lot in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is indeed a bug in the current release of RStudio: `data.frame`s containing Date objects are not rendered properly in notebooks. You might try installing the latest daily build of RStudio and confirming the issue is resolved there:

http://dailies.rstudio.com

Comment: Indeed, using the 1.1.89 solved the problem. Thanks a lot !

Answer (score 1):

I appreciate Rigoberta's and Kevin's posts.  I'm having the same problem (rstudio 1.0.136).

I'm afraid of using the latest daily build as per described in http://dailies.rstudio.com: "Daily builds are intended for testing purposes, and are not recommended for general use. For stable builds, please visit rstudio.com."

As I never used "unstable" versions of rstudio it seems a better approach to rollback rstudio version for now but opinions are appreciated.

While waiting to decide whether to move back to RStudio 1.0.44 or move forward to an "unstable" version, I found out the issue doesn't happen with matrix objects, to, temporarily, I'm using print(as.matrix()):

````
```{r}
df <- data.frame(date = c("31/08/2011", "31/07/2011", "30/06/2011"), values = c(0.8378, 0.8457, 0.8147))
df$dateformatted <- as.Date(strptime(df$date, '%d/%m/%Y'))

print(as.matrix(df), quote = FALSE)
```
     date       values dateformatted
[1,] 31/08/2011 0.8378 2011-08-31   
[2,] 31/07/2011 0.8457 2011-07-31   
[3,] 30/06/2011 0.8147 2011-06-30
````

To simulate the head()'s behaviour:

```
print(as.matrix(df), quote = FALSE, max = length(df) * 6)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this function

```
bf <- function(x) x %>% ungroup() %>% mutate_if(is.Date, as.character)
```

to make dataframes containing dates display as expected

````
```{r}
data.frame(date = as.Date(Sys.time()), num = 1:3) %>% bf
```
````

date       num

2017-03-18  1
2017-03-18  2
2017-03-18  3
3 rows